# AIR iOS- very strange publish error

Tags: ios, air, air-native-extension

Getting the following error when publishing-deploying to iPad running iOS7 from the Flash IDE

```
Invalid input.

ld: -pie can only be used when targeting iOS 4.2 or later
```

Was able to publish before without issue but had to do a restore on the device and update the iOS from 6 to 7.

Wondering if perhaps this error could be a compatibility issue with one of the 2 native extensions I am using and iOS7

```
com.milkmangames.extensions.GoViral
eu.alebianco.air.extensions.analytics.NativeGATracker
```

Compiling using the latest AIR SDK 3.9, using Flash CS6 IDE.

Anyone have a clue and-or see this error before? Googling turns up nada.

Comment: Me too facing the same kind of issue when using native extension, when I try to build the app with Flex 4.6 with Air 3.3 sdk it is working fine but when I build with Apache 4.11 with Air 3.9 I'm getting the same error also one more error 

    ld: -pie can only be used when targeting iOS 4.2 or later
    Compilation failed while executing : ld64

Answer (score 0):

Adobe AIR 3.9 have support for PIE enabled build for IOS, so you need to rebuild the ANE to support for latest SDK

You will need to change the line in **platform-iphone.xml**:

```
<option>-ios_version_min 4.0</option>
```

to:

```
<option>-ios_version_min 4.2</option>
```

and rebuild the ANE to make it work.

see:

[Adobe Forum Post](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1248260)

[As3GameGears Blog](http://www.as3gamegears.com/blog/ios-packaging-failed-against-air-3-8/)